# send CKEDITOR text to email at CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, ckeditor

I need a editor to write an email, then I need to send them by CodeIgniter (v2.2.6) email library to a specific email.

I used CKEDITOR (v4.5.9) for the text email.
I have got successfully received the email but without style nor colors!

and also \r\n\r\n for heading or newlines at the received email.

```
$this->load->library('email');
$this->email->clear();
$this->email->initialize(array(
'protocol' => 'smtp',
'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
'smtp_user' => 'x@gmail.com',
'smtp_pass' => 'mmmm',
'mailtype' => 'html',
'charset'  =>  'ISO-8859-1',
'MIME-Version' => '1.0',
'Content-Type' => 'html',
'smtp_port' => 465,
'crlf' => "\n",
'newline' => "\r\n"
));

$email  ='y@gmail.com';

$subject= "subject" ;
$message = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["editor1"]);

$this->email->from('x@gmail.com', 'P');
$this->email->to($email);


$this->email->subject('subject' );
$this->email->message($message)
$this->email->send();
```

Answer (score 1):

ckeditor will give you the content without the wrapping `<html>` and `<body>` elements. Before setting your `$message`, you need to add some wrapping html with your desired styles in the `head` element. Then take the new string with the wrapping html and ckeditor content and assign it as your `$message`.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            [[ Add your styles here ]]
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        [[ Your ckeditor content goes here ]]
    </body>
</html>
```